# Graded readers for Modern Hebrew?

Tags: graded-readers, hebrew

Graded readers are considered to be good resources for both intensive and extensive reading, especially for people who are not yet proficient enough in an L2 to read texts written for native speakers.

Where can people find graded readers for *Modern* Hebrew?

edit: the question is meant for Modern Hebrew. I should have specified that from the beginning, even though there are no "native speakers" for Biblical Hebrew.

Answer (score 2):

For Biblical Hebrew, you will find a commonly used item here: [Graded Reader of Biblical Hebrew: A Guide to Reading the Hebrew Bible](https://zondervanacademic.com/products/graded-reader-of-biblical-hebrew) by Miles V. Van Pelt and Gary D. Pratico (Zondervan Academic, 2006). This item by Van Pelt and Pratico is a follow-up to their excellent beginning Hebrew book/workbook set and is used by some colleges for an advanced Hebrew course.

Another one you could find is [A Graded Reader of Biblical Hebrew: Mastering Different Literary Styles from Simple to Advanced](https://www.prpbooks.com/book/a-graded-reader-of-biblical-hebrew) by William Fullilove (P & R Books, 2018). It also is a follow-up to an introduction to Hebrew book.

I have the Van Pelt/Pratico Hebrew textbook and will be getting their reader (required for my college course). I took a quick look at the Fullilove book and it simply lists some texts, line by line, with ample spacing for you to work out a translation. It also provides numerous footnotes to help understand difficult phrasing. However, the Van Pelt book appears to provide a more extensive review or explanation of the word groups. In that respect, the Van Pelt might be more useful for continued learning.

Comment: Thanks. I meant Modern Hebrew, but that's my fault for not specifying.

Answer (score 0):

I purchased about 40 Children's books in Modern Hebrew, from Dr. Seuss level to advanced Hebrew, from judaicaused.com.   It is a used book store.  They specialize in Judaica; however, they have a large selection of Modern Hebrew books.  To find these books, search "ילדים" and you will get a list of books to select from.  And, since they are used books, you get them at a discount.

Reading Children's books with their limited vocabulary and repetitive style helped me learn the language.

Hope this helped.